# Xceed Datagrid virtualizing mode issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, xceed, xceed-datagrid

I have a very strange issue in wpf extended toolkit datagrid.

If I use a normal binding, all OK:

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl ItemsSource="{Binding DbTags.Local}"/>
```

But in virtualizing mode text is invisible, but rows is exist.

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <xcdg:DataGridVirtualizingQueryableCollectionViewSource x:Key="QueryableViewSource" QueryableSource="{Binding Path=DbTags}"/>
</Grid.Resources>

<xcdg:DataGridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource QueryableViewSource}}"/>
```

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOxhf.png)

Thank You for helping

Answer (score 0):

It is strange, but all work properly with sort "OrderBy" or "OrderByDescending".

If I set QueryableSource to DbSet without sort or other query, text is hided.

```
public IQueryable<DB.Tag> DbTags
        {
            get
            {
                return _localTagsContext.Tags.OrderByDescending(x =>x.Num);
            }
        }
```